# DataMember being concatenated into comma separated string

Tags: c#, datacontract

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<string>))]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
public class User
{
    public object websites { get; set; }
}
```

Websites can be an array of strings or a single string. If it does indeed come through as an array of strings... It gets automatically concatenated into a comma separated string. How do I prevent this? I need it to be a List

When I try a string[], it seems to fail on this:

**Array:**

```
{
    websites: [ "http://www.google.com", "http://www.whatever.com" ]
}
```

**Single string**

```
{
    websites: "http://www.google.com"    
}
```

Comment: If it needs to be a list why have you typed it as `dynamic`? Where is the data coming from? Who's deserializing it and from what?

Comment: It's coming from an API... It's in JSON format... I have no idea what dynamic means except that it doesn't crash :) It varies from List<string> and string so it cannot be explicitly defined.

Comment: Make it an array of strings, and treat it like an array of strings.

Comment: It seems to fail to map it to that?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: It's sounds like a pretty bad idea to use `dynamic` here. Use a `List<string>` and always send an array, even if it only has one member. If you *absolutely* can't change that on the client side, then you'll need some custom serialization to examine the `websites` property and turn it into a `List<string>` if it's just a single string. It's pretty bad form to pass a single item to something called website**s**.

Comment: Can you provide two examples of JSONs you're receiving, one with a single string and the other one with multiple strings?

Comment: @MattBurland, I don't think he gets to choose what's being sent by API.

Comment: @Tonci: Then they will need to provide custom serialization. In something like Json.Net this is easily done by deriving from `JsonConverter`.

Comment: And how do you deserialize this? Seems to be working fine with "public object websites" and Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: I don't use Newton soft... I use Microsoft 's one (System.Runtime.Serialization)

Comment: Can I have a sample of how to do custom serialization?

Comment: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject); is for basic serialization. By default, this serializes only public fields/properties, but this can easily be changed with attributes.

Comment: Hey guys! hope you had an awesome weekend... What's the answer here? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need to have those attributes on `User`. If not, this code works fine:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonOne = "{ websites: \"http://www.google.com\" }";
        var jsonMany = "{ websites: [ \"http://www.google.com\", \"http://www.whatever.com\" ] }";

        var userOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonOne);
        var userMany = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonMany);

        Debug.WriteLine(":: One ::");
        Print(userOne);

        Debug.WriteLine(":: Many ::");
        Print(userMany);
    }

    static void Print(User user)
    {
        if(user.websites is string)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This user has a single website: {0}", user.websites);
        }

        if (user.websites is JArray)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This user has following websites:");
            foreach (var website in (JArray)user.websites)
                Debug.WriteLine(website);
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public object websites { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
:: One ::
This user has a single website: http://www.google.com
:: Many ::
This user has following websites:
http://www.google.com
http://www.whatever.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately my model is used everywhere, is there any other way with Microsoft's System.Runtime.Serialization?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use for deserializing?

Comment: Tonci, I thought to myself, life is too short... I ended up swapping everything for newtonsoft... it took a while but will save me ball ache later. Thanks for your help man :D

Comment: That's a smart decision! :-) Glad I could help!